# How can pip/poetry find the python modules under a non-root directory like 'src'?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have structured our python project in a typical manner:

```
project root
|--src
    |--my_pkg
          -- my_module.py
          --__init__.py
    |--tests
```

I have followed [poetry docs for include/exclude](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude)

[image]

Based on that I added the following to `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
..
include = ["src/*"]
```

But i get

```
 ValueError

  my_pkg is not a package.
```

How can I tell `poetry` to look under `src` for the `my_pkg.my_module` ?

Comment: Use `poetry new --src my-pkg` to get the initial project setup with `src`-layout. https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#new

Comment: @sinoroc  Thanks that's useful.  I do have a structure already that mimics the directory structure created off that command

Answer (score 2):

Don't put a `__init__.py` in the `src` folder. There's no need for it.

If you have this in your `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-pkg"
```

Poetry will find `my_pkg` in the `src` automatically. But you can be more explicit by:

```
[tool.poetry]
# ...
packages = [
    { include = "my_pkg", from = "src" },
]
```

See https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages

Comment: Oh I did not actually add `__init__.py` in `src`: i just corrected the question.  Thanks for the note about the `[tool.poetry]` packages spec . I'll try that later today: right now have used symlink to try to get this to work and want to see how that performs. Upvoting in the meantime for the usefulness

Answer (score 1):

I'm building an AWS Lambda function, so my source directory is pretty bare-bones:

```
src
├── foo.py
└── bar.py
```

I've found that I need this in my `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "baz"
packages = [ { include = "*.py", from = "src" } ]
```

Note: no mention of the package name in the `packages` entry.